# Reading a csv file (utf-8) and outputting and merging utf-8 strings

Tags: python, string, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have some problems with encoding utf-8 when I read and write a file. I have a CSV file containing Danish and Swedish Letters (ÅÄÖ etc). I want to read this file and extract a field - and manipulate the data (to create urls).

What I am struggling with is the following:

- I cannot read a file containing utf-8 letters - python outputs `\xd6` instead of `ö`.
- I cannot merge two strings even though I am decoding them as (utf-8)

I have tried the following:

- adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
- `Companies = codecs.open("Axel_List.csv", "r", "utf-8")` (reading the file with codecs lib), which produces this error - `'utf' codec can't byte 0xe4 in position 0`
- `url=u'http://www.proff.se/bransch-sök?q='` and `url='http://www.proff.se/bransch-sök?q='` followed by `url.decode('utf-8')` which produces the same error when I try to join the two strings:
  `UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii codec can't encode character u'\xf6 in position 29`

I can print the Company (even though they do not contain the correct letters) and the url separately, so there is something going on when I am joining them.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import codecs
import os, sys
Google_urls=open('google_Urls','w')
Proff_urls=open('Proff_Urls','w')
Companies=("Company_List.csv")

for line in Companies:
    fields = line.split(",")
        if fields[10]=="Sweden":
            Company=(fields[1]).split("/v")
            Company=str(Company).replace('[',"")
            ... stripping and manipulating the records 
            ...
            Company=Company.decode('utf-8')
            url='http://www.proff.se/bransch-sök?q='
            url=url.decode('utf-8')
            Proff_se= ''.join((url,Company,"\n"))
            Proff_urls.write(Company) 
    else:
        continue
```

Why I keep thinking there is something weird going on when I am reading the file is that I have tested this, and it works fine.

```
# coding=utf-8
Svenska="äöå"
Dan_Nor="æøå"
Svenska=Svenska.decode('utf-8')
Dan_Nor=Dan_Nor.decode('utf-8')
string3 ="".join((Svenska,Dan_Norlow,Dan_NorCapital))
print string3
```

Thanks in advance, I have read a lot of questions related to these but I cannot really wrap my head around it.

Comment: Please paste the actual exception rather than trying to reproduce it from memory. The codecs module will not complain about a `'utf'` codec, but about `'utf-8'`, and it will give you additional information about the problem which might help us if you hadn't thrown it away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly that your files aren't actually UTF-8, so trying to read them as if they were UTF-8 is failing. In particular, you claim that using `codecs.open("Axel_List.csv", "r", "utf-8")` and then reading the file gives you this error:

```
'utf' codec can't byte 0xe4 in position 0
```

So, clearly, either it isn't really UTF-8, or it's corrupted.

Normally, it's hard to guess the encoding of a file without actually having the file. But in this case, it's easy.

Byte 0xe4 is `ä` in Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1). And `ä` is the first character that your code is looking for. So, your file is probably Latin-1.

The same byte is also `ä` in two other legacy encodings sometimes used in Scandinavia, Latin-4 and Latin-6 (ISO-8859-4 and -10), so your file *could* be one of these.

In UTF-8, 0xe4 is a lead-byte for CJK characters. Unless you suspect that you really have a corrupted Japanese text file rather than a valid Swedish one, your file is definitely not UTF-8.

Comment: I think you were correct, I managed to run Companies = codecs.open("test.csv", "r","Latin-1"). I tried to print the file, and I still got xc4...etc.  I ran company.decode('Latin-1') - and still got the same result. I guess really need to read up about this but, if you have a quick fix it would be helpful.

Comment: @AxelEricsson: When you say "I tried to print the file", what exactly do you mean? For example, if you get everything right, and you have, say, the list `[u'Ä']`, and print it to a properly-configured terminal, you will see  `[u'\xc4']`.

Comment: How do I get this actually print Ä and not [u'\xc4']?

Comment: @AxelEricsson: Well, first, if you print a list, you're going to get a list display. Second, list displays print the `repr`, or "programmer-readable representation", of each element, not the `str`, or "end-user-readable representation". If you want to print the `str` of each element, you have to either loop over them and print them separately, or come up with your own formatting, like `', '.join(my_list_of_strings)`.

Comment: @AxelEricsson: If that's mot enough to go on (and searching SO and the tutorial/docs for more info on str, repr, etc. doesn't help), create a new question—show your code, exactly what you're doing, what output you're expecting, and what you're getting—rather than just trying to describe it vaguely (which is all you can really do in a comment on an existing question).

Comment: Thank you!! I figured it out... It the fact that it has been a list the whole time. Ugh, I need to learn python better. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it.